# Get site collection users programmatically

Tags: site-collection

How do I get all site collection users programmatically? I want all the users not the groups.

Comment: Via Compiled Code (C#) or Script (PowerShell)?

Comment: Not with powershell. Via Complied code

Answer (score 2):

Use `SPWeb.SiteUsers` to get all users in the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to itterate through all the groups in a site collection and get all users in these groups like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class RetrieveAllUsersAllGroups
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new     ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection");
            GroupCollection collGroup = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;

            clientContext.Load(collGroup);

        clientContext.Load(collGroup,
            groups => groups.Include(
                group => group.Users));

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Group oGroup in collGroup)
        {
            UserCollection collUser = oGroup.Users;

            foreach (User oUser in collUser)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group ID: {0} Group Title: {1} User: {2} Login Name: {3}", 
                    oGroup.Id, oGroup.Title, oUser.Title, oUser.LoginName);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

}